# Does condition selection preserve order in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example,

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'], 'age':[10,20,30]})

  name  age
0    a   10
1    b   20
2    c   30

df[df['age'] > 10]

  name  age
1    b   20
2    c   30
```

My question is: Does Pandas make sure the index order is preserved?
Is any possible the result like:

```
  name  age
2    c   30
1    b   20
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes, filtering preserve order of rows (also index values).

Need to sort by column `age` if need change ordering:

```
df1 = df[df['age'] > 10].sort_values('age', ascending=False)
print (df1)
  name  age
2    c   30
1    b   20
```

Comment: thanks, it'sure do something sort on index can preserve order. My data is some how large, > 200G, I am not sure the cost of sort is necessary.

Comment: @adroot - Hmmm, then not understand your question. Because if `df[df['age'] > 10]` return indices `1,2` it preserve order. So maybe answer should be - `yes, filtering preserve order`

Comment: thanks. yes, my question is about order keeping. @zipa give a good example.

Comment: @adroot please accept this answer. Helps people find it more acceptable

Answer (score 2):

It preserves the data order, doesn't sort the data by any attribute automatically.

Here you can see that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'], 'age':[30,20,10]}, index=[1,0,2])

df[df['age']>10]
#   age name
#1   30    a
#0   20    b
```

Comment: thanks for your inspired example, it make me sure that the order is preserved.